# Sonarqube - use MySQL NDB Cluster

Tags: mysql, sonarqube

As I'm already having a MySQL NDB Cluster database configured with NDB storage engine configured, I want to use it for Sonarqube DB. As in the official sonarqube documentation NDB is not stated as supported, is it possible to make some reconfigurations in the table creation sonarqube bootstrap in order to include "TABLESPACE  STORAGE DISK ENGINE NDBCLUSTER; ending ?

Thanks,
Kiril

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to add a line before the creation of the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Another method to handle is it to use an ALTER TABLE statement moving it from InnoDB to an NDB table with the above tablespace definition